# How to use switch with character strings?

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to create a guessing game where if the player guesses one of many correct strings he will win. Although the switch statement will work with a single letter in the switch parenthesis but it wont work if i put my string in it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include < iostream>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:

    void Guess();
};
void Guess()
{
char guess;
char* word1 = "Dog";
char* word2 = "Cat";


    cout <<"Welcome to guess the word. Get ready..." <<endl;
    cout <<"Guess the word: " <<endl;
    cin >>guess;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) //give the player 3 trys at guessing
    {

    switch(guess)
        {
        case 'Dog':
            cout <<"Dog is correct." <<endl;
            i = 3;
            break;

        default:
            cout <<guess <<" is incorrect." <<endl;
            cin >>guess;




        }
    }
}

int main()
{
  Guess();
  char f;
  cin >>f;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is very badly broken on many levels. It may be more productive to [read a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) first.

Comment: ... And to get it to compile before posting it

Comment: just wondering. whats so bad about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `switch` with strings. This is incorrect:

```
case 'Dog': ...
```

`Dog` is a multibyte character constant, not a string. The compiler should issue a warning about it.

Moreover, `guess` is a single character. It needs to be a string as well. You should use `std::string`, like this:

```
std::string guess;
cout <<"Guess the word: " <<endl;
cin >>guess;
if (guess == "Dog") ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a switch statement can only compare basic data types, such as `int` or `char`. You would need to use a series of `if` statements to check whole strings, either using the equality operator (==) for `std::string` objects, or `strcmp` for C-style strings.

(Be careful not to use the equality operator for C-style strings, as that will only compare the pointer value and not the string content.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `std::string` for the strings to compare.
2. Replace switch with `if(...) { ... } else if(...) {...}`

`switch`-`case` only works for integral types and `'Dog'` is <strike>not a single</strike> a multi-byte character that could be converted to `int` but not a string. Note, that strings like `"Dog"` must be embraced in double-quotes.

Comment: “`'Dog'` is not a single character that could be converted to `int`.” Actually, it is, though the value is implementation-defined.